# KAA Endpoint Ownership, VerifiersDemo for Android, Google Verifier not enabled

Tags: endpoint, kaa

Why is the Android demo for Verifiers only running with Facebook and Twitter verifier? I Uncommented the Google plus verifier stuff, the android APK can be generated on Android Studio but the android app crashes on android device, placing those stuff back in comments and regenerating the APK via Android Studio, the android app will work again on the device.

Is there a working sample/demo using Google Verifier, specially on Android and objective C?

Comment: Update: I tested twitter verifier by actually creating my own twitter account, oddly enough the android app does not even get to the log in screen for twitter input, error shows as 'failed to get request token' so now it looks like the User Verifier Demo android app only works with facebook. Please help make the google verifier and twitter verifier also work for this Android demo on User Verifiers.

Comment: Update: Worked on Android source code,found the app actually uses values for consumer key/secret from strings.xml,so I created new Twitter App,used new key and secret values in strings.xml,changed the user verifier values for these on Kaa Server.Rebuilt APK,tested again,finally works.Authentication,ownership,and events now work properly.Also worth noting that the new Twitter App I created under settings,added a Callback URL,it seems to solve the 'failed to get request token'.Now remaining non working feature of android app is google verifier.Any help will be greatly appreciated,THANKS.

Comment: Uncommented all Google Verifier in Android sample code. Created a Google Developer account, and configured there a credential for app, used the client id provided by google and used it in the android source code. Rebuilt and installed apk, now the android app does not crash and gets up to the point where you can choose google account to log in, but after log in, Error 10, Authentication error. I think this is something now about either how the Google dev credential was wrongly created or the Kaa 0.10.0 maybe is incomplete implementation. Can anybody please help on this.